# How is "<!-- [if IE X]> something something <![endif] -->" applied?

Tags: html, conditional-comments

In modern web pages you often see something like:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The purpose is obviously to apply different html, depending on browser and browser version. I assume this is done server side, as it seems everything except the appropriate parts are commented out.

What software is used on the server to select which part to comment out depending on the visiting browser?

Comment: And this was, sadly, a less-dumb mistaken than the IE browser modes .. in any case, conditional comments are also used in Microsoft Office (MSO) / SharePoint internals, although you'll likely never see that. Hopefully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). They are parsed (contrary to the HTML spec), client side, by Internet Explorer (versions 5-9). Everything else (including IE 10) treats them as regular comment syntax.